# Register custom plugins globally in vitest

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vitest

I have a lot of vittest files and i want to register the plugins globally for all test files.
Currently most of the test files are mounting the `VueWrapper` as follows.

```
  const wrapper = shallowMount(MyComponent, {
    global: {
      plugins: [i18n, MyCustomPlugin, [MyCustomLoggerPlugin, 'MyCustomParameter']],
    },
    props: {
    },
  })
```

Is there a way that i can remove the plugin installation from the mount function and do this globally? I18n should stay in the test files as the localizations are different for each component.

Comment: Write your own wrapper for shallowMount and merge its options if necessary

Comment: Can you provide a sample?

Comment: Something like? myMount = (comp, { plugins = [], ...opts } = {}) => shallowMount(comp, { ...opts, global: {...opts.global, plugins: [...plugins, [MyPlugin] ] } )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by creating a vitetest.setup.ts

```
import { config } from '@vue/test-utils'
import MyCustomPlugin, { MyCustomLoggerPlugin} from 'xyz'

config.global.plugins = [
  MyCustomPlugin,
  [MyCustomLoggerPlugin, 'MyCustomParameter'],
]
```

this file has to be registered in vite.config.ts.

```
test: {
    setupFiles: ['vitest.setup.ts'],
  },
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://vitest.dev/config/#setupfiles).